# ListView Group Header Click - How to add a context menu to ListView Group Headers?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, contextmenu

I use a `ListView` in my WinForms application, which contains a lot of values and also a few groups. The group headers only show the name of the group, so i want to add a context menu to the group header with an item "Show description" to show a long summary of the Group.

After googling a while I only found third party controls which have this functionality.

How can I add the `ContextMenu` to the Group header without using 3rd party software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a [`LVM_HITTEST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) message to `ListView`. When you pass `-1` to `wParam`, if the return value is greater than `-1` and `LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER` has been set in the result, the return value of `SendMessage` method will be clicked group index.

**Implementation**

In below implementations, I've added `GroupHeaderClick` event to `MyListView` class. You can simply handle the event this way:

```
private void myListView1_GroupHeaderClick(object sender, int e)
{
    //Show ContextMenuStrip here. Or just for example:
    MessageBox.Show(myListView1.Groups[e].Header);
}
```

Here is `MyListView` implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public event EventHandler<int> GroupHeaderClick;
    protected virtual void OnGroupHeaderClick(int e)
    {
        var handler = GroupHeaderClick;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
    private const int LVM_HITTEST = 0x1000 + 18;
    private const int LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER = 0x10000000;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LVHITTESTINFO
    {
        public int pt_x;
        public int pt_y;
        public int flags;
        public int iItem;
        public int iSubItem;
        public int iGroup;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg,
        int wParam, ref LVHITTESTINFO ht);
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        var ht = new LVHITTESTINFO() { pt_x = e.X, pt_y = e.Y };
        var value = SendMessage(this.Handle, LVM_HITTEST, -1, ref ht);
        if (value != -1 && (ht.flags & LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER) != 0)
            OnGroupHeaderClick(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please comment your code (especially the OnMouseDown Method)? I dont want to copy and paste code i dont fully understand

Comment: In fact in `OnMouseDown` you should send [`LVM_HITTEST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) message to `ListView`. Then you should check if the result  is greater than -1 and the [`LVHITTESTINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774754(v=vs.85).aspx) which you passed to `SendMessage` contains `LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER` flag, it means the result is index of clicked header group.  Rest of code is  declarations and [raising event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I added [`LVM_HITTEST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link, read parameters and return value section :)

Answer (score 1):

The Reza Aghaei's solution works only if the groups are added before the items. In case a group is added after the items have been added already, it fails, because the SendMessage function returns wrong indices. It actually returns the IDs not indices. That is a known problem in the ListView component. The idea is to compare the returned value to the Group ID.

```
public class WListView : ListView
{
    #region [ PInvoke ]

    private const int LVM_HITTEST = 0x1000 + 18;
    private const int LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST = 0x1000 + 57;
    private const int LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER = 0x10000000;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LVHITTESTINFO
    {
        public int pt_x;
        public int pt_y;
        public int flags;
        public int iItem;
        public int iSubItem;
        public int iGroup;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, ref LVHITTESTINFO ht);

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a group is clicked.
    /// </summary>
    [Category("Behavior")]
    [Description("Occurs when a group header is clicked.")]
    public event EventHandler<ListViewGroupClickEventArgs> GroupClick;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the GroupClick event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
    protected virtual void OnGroupHeaderClick(ListViewGroupClickEventArgs e)
    {
        GroupClick?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the Control.MouseDoubleClick event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        var group = TestGroupHit(e);
        if (group == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (e.Clicks)
        {
            case 1:
                OnGroupHeaderClick(new ListViewGroupClickEventArgs(group));
                break;
        }
    }

    private ListViewGroup TestGroupHit(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var ht = new LVHITTESTINFO { pt_x = e.X, pt_y = e.Y };
        var msg = View == System.Windows.Forms.View.Details ? LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST : LVM_HITTEST;
        var value = SendMessage(Handle, msg, -1, ref ht);

        if (value != -1 && (ht.flags & LVHT_EX_GROUP_HEADER) != 0)
        {
            return FindGroupByID(value);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private ListViewGroup FindGroupByID(int id)
    {
        foreach (ListViewGroup group in Groups)
        {
            if (group.ExtractID() == id)
            {
                return group;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The property Group.ID is non-public. Here is the extension that extracts it.

```
public static int ExtractID(this ListViewGroup group)
    {
        try
        {
            return (int) group
                .GetType()
                .GetProperty("ID", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .GetValue(group, new object[0]);
        }
        catch 
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Note that Reflection may be time-consuming depending on the context.

Comment: This should be the real answer. I searched the web for literally 6 hours straight trying to figure out why all of these solutions were not working. I finally figured out that it was actually giving me the ID instead of the index but didn't know how to complete it without your solution. I would upvote this a billion times if I could. I cannot thank you enough!!!!!!!!!